# Check a variable to make certain that it is all numbers?

Tags: cobol

How can I check Work-Trig to make sure that it is all digits?

code:

Work-Trig is -->  20140101

```
CHECK-TRIG.                          
    IF WORK-TRIG IS NUMERIC THEN     
       MOVE "FALSE" TO ERR-TRIG      
    ELSE                             
       MOVE "TRUE" TO ERR-TRIG       
    END-IF.                          
    DISPLAY 'ERR-TRIG' ERR-TRIG.     
X-CHECK. EXIT.  

01  WORK-TRIG.                               
 05 TRIG-YEAR  PIC X(08) VALUE SPACES.    
 05 TRIG-MONTH PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.    
 05 TRIG-DAY   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.    
 05 FILLER     PIC X(70) VALUE SPACES.
```

Comment: That looks right, assuming you want to display `FALSE` when the value is all numeric.  With GNU Cobol, `20140101` displays `FALSE`, `2014010a` displays `TRUE`   For testing here WORK-TRIG defined as PIC X(8).

Comment: How is WORK-TRICK defined?

Comment: If this is OK now Doug, can you select Close for the question? If we can get it closed, I think the system will remove it automatically (because there are no answers). If there is a problem still, update the question with the details requested. Thanks.

Comment: Does that take away from my points. I clicked on close and there is no place that is just for a question to close because of a correct answer or the question was resolved.

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect your reputation points. Questions are not closed as in "solved", but closed if they are unanswerable, duplicate, can't be reproduced, not a fit for the site, typos, etc. Have a read through the Help Centre (help on the top bar). There's now an answer anyway.

Comment: I see you have an upvote on the question now. That I think you would have then lost, if the question was closed and removed, but that wasn't there when I made the comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that WORK-TRIG is 80 bytes long. The first eight bytes contain your data, but the entire 80 bytes will be tested for being NUMERIC.

You have a data-name for the first eight bytes. If you test that instead of the group-item, your code will work.

```
CHECK-TRIG.                          
    IF WORK-YEAR IS NUMERIC THEN     
       MOVE "FALSE" TO ERR-TRIG      
    ELSE                             
       MOVE "TRUE" TO ERR-TRIG       
    END-IF.                          
    DISPLAY 'ERR-YEAR' ERR-TRIG.     
X-CHECK. EXIT.
```

If you have a data-name called WORK-YEAR, it should only contain a year. It should not contain an entire date. The point of good names for data is so that we, humans, can read and understand your code better. When looking for a problem, we find WORK-YEAR as eight bytes long, and have to spend time finding out if that is the correct length, or the correct name and a wrong length.

Given the code change, it would be good to use a different name for ERR-TRIG as well.

There are more obscure ways to test the first eight bytes of a group item, but since you already had a name, hopefully we'll keep reference-modification out of this one.

Answer (score 1):

The following code example works and will check each position in you WORK-TRIG1 to see if that value is a NUMERIC. I tested this and it does work. This example uses a PERFORM VARYING loop to index through each "location" in the string to see if it is valid.

```
  Should Work ALSO:

        IF A IS NUMERIC THEN
           //code here
        END-IF
```

I do know that the below code works because I took it directly from a program that is running perfectly and has since 88 or 89.

Code:

```
CHECK-TRIG.                                                          
    PERFORM VARYING SUB1 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL SUB1 > 8                  
      IF WORK-TRIG(1:SUB1) IS NUMERIC THEN                           
         MOVE 'FALSE' TO ERR-TRIG                                    
      ELSE                                                           
         MOVE 'TRUE' TO ERR-TRIG                                     
         MOVE SUB1   TO SV-RTN-CODE 
         MOVE 9 TO SUB1                                 
      END-IF                                                         
    END-PERFORM.                                                     
X-CHECK. EXIT.
```

--Code--New this does not work

```
PERFORM VARYING SUB1 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL SUB1 > 8          
  IF WORK-TRIG(SUB1:8) IS NUMERIC THEN                   
     MOVE 'FALSE' TO ERR-TRIG                            
  ELSE                                                   
     MOVE 'TRUE' TO ERR-TRIG                             
     MOVE SUB1   TO SV-RTN-CODE                          
     MOVE '   TRIGGER CARD ERROR (SEE DATE BELOW)' TO    
          ERR-DET                                        
     MOVE 9 TO SUB1                                      
  END-IF                                                 
END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: That is truly, truly, horrible code. I suggest not copying code like that, even if it does "work". Please, do not `GO TO` out of an in-line `PERFORM` and do not `GO TO` out of the range of any `PERFORM`.

Comment: That is how a lot of our code works at the company that I work at. I would agree that a go to is terrible but you should see some of the stuff that we have. I looked at one yesterday that had go to's that jumped all over the program. I finally had to print it out and you three different colored highlighter pens to figure out where I was going.

Comment: Commiserations. That sounds bad. The coloured marker pens and listing is good. I would say keep doing that, until you can do it in your head. Do it with loops. Do it will CALLs. Do it with data from file reads. My first-best-programming-tools were pencil and paper. Gradually you get able to do it in your head, but a really good way to get a grip on it. I'd just say, don't copy the bad code. Something that "works" isn't necessarily anything which should be shown in public, however well-intentioned.

Comment: OK. Good on getting rid of the GO TO. You should look to use `PERFORM UNTIL...` and, if insisting on the reference modification, use `( SUB1 : 1)`. At the moment, you are testing the first byte eight times, the second seven, the third six, etc. The `8` describes nothing. Give it a name. Set `ERR-TRIG` to `FALSE` outside the loop, so you don't need ELSE. Realise that this, even once it is tidied up, is both slower and less clear than the single test for NUMERIC.

Comment: isn't Var(1:MyIndex) doesn't that loop through each byte or how would I do it so that I check each individual byte. ALPHABETIC was not working?

Comment: No. In the example you show, `MyIndex` is the *length* of the field, and `1` is the start of the field. Not sure what you mean that `ALPHABETIC` was not working.

Comment: So it should be myVar(Index:8)  Isn't ALPHABETIC used in an if statement to see if all bytes are alphabetic   if a is Alphabetic then

Comment: You can look at the first eight bytes at once with reference-modification ( 1 : 8 ), or you can look at the first eight, one byte at a time, with reference modification ( subscript : 1 ). What you copied, was looking from byte 1, length 1, next byte 1, length 2, next byte 1, length 3, etc. Yes, ALPHABETIC to check for that. Look at Class Tests in the manuals. Know what is available, and that you can make your own.

Comment: Forget to mention how much I dislike reference-modification myself :-)

Comment: Can you show how you would do it. I would imagine that it would be better but it would be something to compare my code with. I posted some code into my question. I used Expideter to step through the code and it worked like I thought it would. I moves one byte to my temp field and then compares that value to the alphabetic. MyVar(index:8) or should it be MyVar(index:1).

Comment: It should be your `MyVar(index:1)`. In your existing code, put `DISPLAY ">" WORK-TRIG(SUB1:8) "<"` immediately before the `IF`. `MOVE "20140101ABCDEFGHI" TO WORK-TRIG` before the `PERFORM` and you'll see what it is doing. The do the same thing with the index:1 in the `DISPLAY` and the `IF`, and compare. You'll see what is happening with both. I would do it the way Doug originally attempted it, but with the eight-byte field, not the 80-byte field. If there was no eight-byte field, I'd just define one. With a descriptive name, so it is clear what is being tested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51832/discussion-between-user3491862-and-bill-woodger)

Answer (score 0):

Recently had experienced non-numeric being successfully processed into a numeric (COMP-3) field.

Value of 'FALSE99999999' moved into a COMP-3 field and became 6132599999999 and the program never encounter an S0C7 ABEND.

Looks like verifying each byte of the source field is the only way to identify such issue.